# Updating multiple Columbus with addslashes value

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been trying to update more than one column on my database with values that have addslashes. I know addslashes isn't recommended, but is there anyways to add more than one value at a time? I've tried adding another value after a "," but it doesn't work.

example:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET note5=('".addslashes($note5)."'), note6=('".addslashes($note6)."') WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];
```

but this does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the brackets around

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET note5='". addslashes($note5)."', note6='".addslashes($note6)."' WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];
```

Note : I would suggest you to use pdo or mysqli prepared statements, which will remove your extra works needed for special characters.

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE users SET note5=("\\", "\\\\", addslashes($note5)), note6=("\\", "\\\\", addslashes($note6)) WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']; Like this?

Comment: Yeah. It did not work. It comes up as an empty page when trying to update these two values.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice before you have an extra bracket around the value, which shouldn't be there. Pls check above the edited answer.

Comment: Hey that did work. However, I was using the addslashes to allow apostrophes to be entered in the users textarea box and this method causes and sql syntax error when I tried to add an apostrophe

Comment: Oh, in that case, actually your previous method was good, just remove the brackets around. (I thought you wanted the backslashes to be inserted to the db)

Comment: You are most welcome. But I would suggest you to use pdo or mysqli prepared statements, which will remove your extra works needed for special characters.